# Groenewold's derivation of the star product (On the principles of elementary Quantum Mechanics)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, phase-space, wigner-transform, deformation-quantization

$\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}$
In the paper "On the principles of elementary Quantum Mechanics" am trying to get from equation EQN 4.25 to EQN 4.27. I need help on exponential identities and integration by parts. Basically I need to get from part **(9) to (10)** of my calculations (Full details after the "--- ---"):

\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{h^2}\int \dd\eta  \dd\xi  \dd\sigma  \dd\tau\,e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}\\
&\qquad\times\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\right)\\
&\qquad\times\left(e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{\delta  (2 \hbar )}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)
\tag{9}\end{align}

Then somehow by partial integrations?

\begin{align}
&=\frac{1}{h^2}\int  \dd\eta  \dd\xi  \dd\sigma  \dd\tau e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\\
&\qquad\times\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)
\end{align}

In summary, how did 
$$\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\right)\left(e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{\delta  (2 \hbar )}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)
$$
"become"
$$e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)?$$ 

It seems $e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}$ in (9) has "slipped" from the differential actions to arrive at (10)

**Relevant Information :**

1. $\frac{\delta}{ \delta \sigma }$, or $\frac{\delta}{ \delta \tau }$ acts to the right, for example :

$$f(\sigma)\frac{\delta}{ \delta \sigma }\sigma = (\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma } f(\sigma) )* \sigma $$
2. Also the operators $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}$ and  $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}$ don't act on anything ; It does nothing on $\sigma$ , $\tau$ , $\xi$ , $\eta$ , a($\sigma$,$\tau$) or b($\sigma$,$\tau$).

"--- ---"

**Full Details :**

$$ \overset{\rightharpoonup }{a} \overset{\rightharpoonup }{b} =\frac{1}{h^4}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau \dd\eta '\dd\xi '\dd\sigma '\dd\tau ' e^{\frac{i \left(\eta  \xi '-\xi  \eta '\right)}{2 \hbar }} e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }} \exp \left(-\frac{i \left(\eta ' \tau '+\eta  \tau +\xi ' \sigma '+\xi  \sigma \right)}{\hbar }\right) a\left(\frac{\sigma '}{2}+\sigma ,\tau -\frac{\tau '}{2}\right) b\left(\sigma -\frac{\sigma '}{2},\frac{\tau '}{2}+\tau \right)$$

$$= \frac{1}{h^4}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau \dd\sigma '\dd\tau ' e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}\int\dd\eta '\dd\xi ' \exp \left(-\frac{i \left(\eta ' \left(\frac{\xi }{2}+\tau '\right)+\xi ' \left(\sigma '-\frac{\eta }{2}\right)\right)}{\hbar }\right) a\left(\frac{\sigma '}{2}+\sigma ,\tau -\frac{\tau '}{2}\right) b\left(\sigma -\frac{\sigma '}{2},\frac{\tau '}{2}+\tau \right)\tag{1}$$

$$= \frac{1}{h^4}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau \dd\sigma '\dd\tau ' e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}\int h * h *d\sigma '\dd\tau ' \delta \left(\sigma '-\frac{\eta }{2}\right) \delta \left(\frac{\xi }{2}+\tau '\right) e^{-\frac{i \left(\eta ' \tau '+\xi ' \sigma '\right)}{\hbar }} a\left(\frac{\sigma '}{2}+\sigma ,\tau -\frac{\tau '}{2}\right) b\left(\sigma -\frac{\sigma '}{2},\frac{\tau '}{2}+\tau \right)\tag{2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{h^2}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{\hbar }} a\left(\frac{\eta }{4}+\sigma ,\tau -\frac{\xi }{4}\right) b\left(\sigma -\frac{\eta }{4},\frac{\xi }{4}+\tau \right) e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}\tag{3}$$

By Taylor theorem :

$$=\frac{1}{h^2}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )+\frac{1}{4}\left(\eta \frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\xi \frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)a(\sigma ,\tau )+\text{...}\right)e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\left(b(\sigma ,\tau )-\frac{1}{4}\left(\eta \frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\xi \frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)b(\sigma ,\tau )+\text{...}\right)\tag{5}
$$

Notice that 
$$e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\frac{1}{4}\left(\eta \frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)a(\sigma ,\tau )=e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)a(\sigma ,\tau )$ where $\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }$$ acts on the left.

$$
=\frac{1}{h^2}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )+\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)a(\sigma ,\tau )+\text{...}\right)e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\left(b(\sigma ,\tau )-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)b(\sigma ,\tau )+\text{...}\right)\tag{6}$$

Another expression for Taylor expansion
$$
= \frac{1}{h^2}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}\left(e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)}a(\sigma ,\tau )\right)\left(e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)
\tag{7}$$

Notice $$e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)}a(\sigma ,\tau )=a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}$$

$$
= \frac{1}{h^2}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\right)\left(e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)
\tag{8}$$

Notice that $$e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)}$ in $e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )$ : $e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\right)}=e^{-\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)}=e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{\delta  (2 \hbar )}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)}$$

$$
=\frac{1}{h^2}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\right)\left(e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{\delta  (2 \hbar )}{i \delta \sigma }\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }-\frac{\delta  (-(2 \hbar ))}{i \delta \tau }\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)\tag{9}$$

Then somehow by partial integrations?
$$
=\frac{1}{h^2}\int\dd\eta \dd\xi \dd\sigma \dd\tau e^{\frac{i \left(\xi  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+\eta  \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}e^{-\frac{i (\eta  \tau +\xi  \sigma )}{2 \hbar }}\left(a(\sigma ,\tau )e^{\frac{1}{4}\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \tau }\frac{\delta }{\delta \sigma }-\left(-\frac{2 \hbar }{i}\frac{\partial }{\partial \sigma }\right)\frac{\delta }{\delta \tau }\right)}b(\sigma ,\tau )\right)\tag{10}
$$

Which by change of variables $(\xi \to x,\eta \to y,\sigma \to p,\tau \to q)$ is equivalent to EQN 4.27

$$\overset{\rightharpoonup }{a} \overset{\rightharpoonup }{b}=\frac{1}{h} \int dxdy e^{\frac{i \left(x \overset{\rightharpoonup }{p}+y \overset{\rightharpoonup }{q}\right)}{\hbar }} \frac{1}{h} \int dpdq e^{-\frac{i (p x+q y)}{\hbar }}\left(a(p,q)e^{\frac{\hbar }{2 i}\left(\frac{\delta }{\text{$\delta $p}}\frac{\partial }{\partial q}-\frac{\delta }{\text{$\delta $q}}\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\right)}b(p,q)\right)$$

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for your math question?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding your tack, but you are certainly taking an alarming left turn from Groenewold's simple and  elegant expressions! In my experience, students get confused by integrations by parts, especially when lots of arguments are concerned. I'd strongly recommend working in multi-Fourier space so there are *no* derivatives present, and the  *  product  Groenewold is deriving is just an integral kernel, easily reducible to his compact bidifferential operator. Look at eqns  (11)-(14), (13), as well as G's proof in (117-119) of [this](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf).

Comment: Hi @CosmasZachos, thankyou for the reply. I need the formulae to be as in (9); my thesis uses an approximation derived from the derivative form. The paper I looked at "On the principles of elementary Quantum Mechanics" seems to be the fastest derivation of it.

Comment: This post (v7) has currently 4 close-votes, and is 1 close-vote short of an automated migration to [math.se]. Note that the Phys.SE community generally allows math questions if they are asked in a physics context, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451) meta post.  I'm closing it as homework to hinder a migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can see it directly, but Cosmas Zachos' suggestion *"to working in multi-Fourier space so there are no derivatives present"* is the most systematic & fool-proof approach. Here is a sketched derivation:
$$\ldots e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(xp+yq)}\left( a(p,q) \exp\left(\frac{\hbar}{2i}\left(\frac{\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\partial}}{\partial p}\frac{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\partial}}{\partial q}-\frac{\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\partial}}{\partial q}\frac{\stackrel{\rightarrow}{\partial}}{\partial p} \right)\right)b(p,q)\right) \tag{4.27}
$$
$$~=~\ldots\left.e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(xp+yq)} \exp\left(\frac{\hbar}{2i}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{\prime}}- \frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{\partial}{\partial p^{\prime}} \right)\right) a(p,q)b(p^{\prime},q^{\prime})\right|^{p^{\prime}=p}_{q^{\prime}=q}  
$$
$$~=~\ldots e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(xp+yq)}\int \! \mathrm{d}p^{\prime}\mathrm{d}q^{\prime}   \delta(p-p^{\prime}) \delta(q-q^{\prime})  \exp\left(\frac{\hbar}{2i}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{\prime}}- \frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{\partial}{\partial p^{\prime}} \right)\right) a(p,q)b(p^{\prime},q^{\prime})  
$$
$$~=~\ldots e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(xp+yq)}\int \! \mathrm{d}p^{\prime}\mathrm{d}q^{\prime}  \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\pi\hbar}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{2\pi\hbar}   e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(u(p-p^{\prime})+v(q-q^{\prime}))}  $$ $$\exp\left(\frac{\hbar}{2i}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial q^{\prime}}- \frac{\partial}{\partial q}\frac{\partial}{\partial p^{\prime}} \right)\right) a(p,q)b(p^{\prime},q^{\prime})  
$$
$$~\stackrel{\text{int. by parts}}{\sim}~\ldots e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(xp+yq)}\int \! \mathrm{d}p^{\prime}\mathrm{d}q^{\prime}  \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\pi\hbar}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{2\pi\hbar}   e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}(u(p-p^{\prime})+v(q-q^{\prime}))}  e^{\frac{i}{2\hbar}(xv-yu)}  a(p,q)b(p^{\prime},q^{\prime})  $$
$$~=~\ldots e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}(xp+yq)}\int \! \mathrm{d}p^{\prime}\mathrm{d}q^{\prime}   \delta(p-\frac{y}{2}-p^{\prime}) \delta(q+\frac{x}{2}-q^{\prime})  a(p,q)b(p^{\prime},q^{\prime})  $$
$$~=~\ldots  a(p,q)b(p-\frac{y}{2},q+\frac{x}{2})  $$
$$~\stackrel{\text{shifting int. var.}}{\sim}~ \ldots a(p+\frac{y}{4},q-\frac{x}{4})b(p-\frac{y}{4},q+\frac{x}{4}). \tag{4.25} $$