# Wigner transform of $O_1 O_2$ in terms of Wigner transforms of $O_1$ and $O_2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, density-operator, wigner-transform

The Wigner-Weyl transform of a quantum operator $O$ is defined as
$$
W[O](q,p) = 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy\ e^{- 2 i p y} \langle q + y | O | q - y \rangle \ dy
$$
and then given a density matrix $\rho$ one can write
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[ O \rho ] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \ W[O](q,p)\ W[\rho](q,p) \ .
$$
**Question**: Suppose we have two operators $O_1$ and $O_2$ each with transforms $W_{1} := W[O_1]$ and $W_{2} := W[O_2]$. Is there a way to express $W[O_1 O_2]$ in terms of $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$? Meaning, is there some way to decompose $W[O_1 O_2] = f(W_1, W_2)$? In particular, is there a way to express
$$
\mathrm{Tr}[ O_1 O_2 \rho ] = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp \ W[O_1 O_2](q,p)\ W[\rho](q,p) \ .
$$
in terms of an integral in terms of $W_1$ and $W_2$? (*ie.* something like $\cdots = \iint dq dp \ W_{1}W_{2}W[\rho]$?)

Comment: Heard [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/731889/obtaining-the-star-product-from-the-weyl-quantisation-of-the-product-of-two-symb), if not [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351559/groenewolds-derivation-of-the-star-product-on-the-principles-of-elementary-qua). You are asking about Groenewold's star product, the fundamental theorem of phase-space QM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notwithstanding the good answer provided by Cosmas Zachos, there is another expression for the star product that is perhaps more convenient to use in certain cases. One can derive it directly from the expression of the Wigner function and the Weyl transform.

Any operator can be expressed in terms of its Wigner function by
$$ \hat{O} = \int |q_1\rangle W_{\hat{O}}\left(\frac{q_1+q_2}{2},p\right) \exp[i p(q_1-q_2)] \langle q_2|\ \frac{\text{d}p}{2\pi}\ \text{d}q_1\ \text{d}q_2 . $$
It can be used to replace the operators in the expression for the Wigner function of the product of two operators
$$ W_{\hat{A}\hat{B}}(q,p) = \int \langle q+x/2| \hat{A}\hat{B}|q-x/2\rangle  \exp(-i px)\ \text{d}x . $$
The overlaps between the quadrature eigenstates and some of the integrals can be evaluated to give
\begin{eqnarray}
& W_{\hat{A}\hat{B}}(q,p) = 4 \int W_{\hat{A}}(q_1,p_1)W_{\hat{B}}(q_2,p_2) \\
& \times \exp[i 2 p_1 (q-q_2)+i 2 p_2 (q_1-q)-i 2 p (q_1-q_2)] \text{d}q_1 \text{d}q_2 \frac{\text{d}p_1}{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}p_2}{2\pi} . 
\end{eqnarray}
It represents the star product
$$ W_{\hat{A}\hat{B}} = W_{\hat{A}}\star W_{\hat{B}} . $$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you are asking about (Groenewold's 1946) fundamental theorem of deformation quantization, e.g.,  equation (148) in [this booklet](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf),

- Noncommutative operator multiplication isomorphically Wigner-maps to $\star$-multiplication in phase-space.

$$
W[O_1 O_2]= W[O_1]\star W[O_2], \\
  f \star g \equiv f(x,p) \, \exp{\left(\frac{i \hbar}{2} \left(\overset{_\gets}\partial_x
\vec\partial_p - \overset{_\gets}\partial_p \vec\partial_x \right) \right)} g(x,p)\\
={1\over \pi^2}\int\!\! dp'dp''dx'dx'' f(x',p')g(x'',p'') \exp \bigl (-2i (p(x'-x'')+p'(x''-x) +p''(x-x'))\bigr ),
$$
where the final, integral, determinantal, form is due to von Neuman (1931) and G Baker (1958), and 1/ℏ has been absorbed into the *p*s.

This $\star$ product starts out as plain multiplication, present in your final conjecture, but then gets corrected by $\hbar$-terms, nonclassical, as it should. $\star$ is noncommutative and associative, and, in this deformation, (Weyl-Moyal), it has an astounding property.

Since tracing operators *O* maps to $\int\!\! dpdx$ in phase space, strictly speaking, $2\pi \operatorname{Tr} W[O_1 O_2]= \int\!\! dpdxW[O_1]\star W[O_2]$. *However*, one star (only) inside a phase-space integral can be trivialized to 1, through integration by parts. This, then, accounts for
$$
2\pi\operatorname{Tr} W[O_1 \rho]= \int\!\! dpdx~W[O_1]\star W[\rho]\\ 
= \int\!\! dpdx~W[O_1] W[\rho],
$$
but dictates
$$
2\pi \operatorname{Tr} W[O_1 O_2 O_3... \rho]= \int\!\! dpdx~W[O_1]\star W[O_2]\star W[O_3]...\star  W[\rho]\\
\int\!\! dpdx~(W[O_1]\star W[O_2]\star W[O_3] ...)~ W[\rho],
$$
in lieu of your expression, which is merely the $O(\hbar^0)$
leading piece of the above.